# Type mismatch on same type

Tags: scala, marshalling, spray

I am trying to send a json response with spray-routing 
 I am getting this error after invoking on complete

```
Error:(45, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : _2.Entities.EventsSearchResponse where val _2: eyein.eventful.eventful
 required: _3.Entities.EventsSearchResponse where val _3: eyein.eventful.eventful
                api.jsonize(value)
                            ^
```

`api.jsonize` is just a wrapper for `marshal`

Using it in the orginal api file prints the json as string with no problems.

I am mostly interested in the the error there is obviously some typing problem but I am not sure where to begin

this is the route

```
val myRoute =
  path("event" / IntNumber / IntNumber) {(from,to) =>
    get {
      respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
        onSuccess(api.GetEventsByDate(from.toString,to.toString)){ value =>
            complete{
              api.jsonize(value)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

jsonize signature

```
  def jsonize(eventList : Entities.EventsSearchResponse)
```

Comment: Unsure about it, but usually when you have type errors of the type "expected X, got X", it's because the X is a different type in the Scala and Java versions. Have you tried checking your imports for java classes?

Comment: can you provide the `jsonize` signature?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I have added the signature

Answer (score 0):

Scala considers the types of inner classes to be path-dependent, and does not always infer path-dependent types the way you'd expect. Try giving it an explicitly path-dependent type:

```
onSuccess(api.GetEventsByDate(...): Future[api.Entities.EventsSearchResponse]) {
  value: api.Entities.EventsSearchResponse => ...
}
```